# SOAP v2 call returns empty object/array on orderInfo

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2

**Magento 1.9.3**

currently testing `SOAP v2` calls on `sales_order.info` with the following code:

```
$proxy = new Client('http://magento.dev/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
$session= $proxy->login('xxx', 'xxx');
$result = $proxy->salesOrderInfo($session, '100000001');
var_dump($result);
$proxy->endSession($session);
```

Returns:

```
object(stdClass)#162 (0) { }
```

---

Though, when I use and try instead for instance,

```
$result = $proxy->directoryCountryList($session);
```

I receive a proper response.

Does someone have a hint for me to look for?
Using `zendframework/zend-soap package`.

Try&Catch won't throw me an exception.

Thanks, alot guys.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `SoapClient` instead of `Client`. So that on line 1:

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magento.dev/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
```

Note: I assume your login info is correct and having permission to access order repository.

Ref: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.info.html